# Algorithm to shuffle data

Tags: algorithm, sorting, shuffle

I have data table (string[][]) like below:

```
0, b, b, b  
0, b, a, c  
0, b, c, b  
0, c, b, a  
1, b, b, c  
1, b, a, b  
0, a, b, c  
0, a, b, b  
...
```

I need to shuffle data by first column (always 2 classes). Lets say there are 100 records in table, so for 50 of '0' and 50 of '1', shuffle should return [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1...]. (<- this is first column result, but it should move all records; shuffle other columns toghether with the first one)
For 33 of '0' and 67 of '1' first column should be [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0...].
There may by diffrent splits like 21-79, 44-56 etc. also there may be more than 100 records eg. 812, 1123...
Is there any algorithm to handle this?
I want programe it in C#, but also i may do it in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First count the number of ones and divide it by the number of rows, so you know the probability p of getting a 1.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if ("1".equals(arr[i][0]))
        count++;
double p = ((double)count) / arr.length;
int[] goal = new int[arr.length];
double t = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < goal.length; i++) {
    t += p;
    if (t >= 1) {
        t--;
        goal[i] = 1;
    } else {
        goal[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Now you can shuffle the rows according to the goal array. Warning the count of the ones in the goal variable could be wrong because of rounding errors (shouldn't be more than 1 difference, so you can just adjust the last element if that happens).

Answer (score 1):

My first (untested) idea is:

```
for i = 0 to 99:
    if 67*i/100 <> 67*(i+1)/100:
        print("1")
    else:
        print("0")
```

And indeed it works: https://play.golang.org/p/gxbZ6np6JZ

Comment: it works fine, but i was not precise enough, so i make some changes in my question.